# Affecting Object's Properties Inside Callbacks in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, iteration

I'm in the process of writing a simple prototype in Node.js with some helper methods that I'll probably need in objects using that prototype. One method that I'd like to have is an implementation of jQuery's [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/). I've looked at jQuery's implementation in their development release, and tried to emulate it in my simplified version here.

```
// Loop through the object using a callback
BaseProto.prototype.each = function (cb, args) {
    var obj = this.get(),   // Get our object as a plain object
        prop;

    /** Code to make sure the the args passed are actually an array **/

    if (typeof cb === "function") {
        // For each property in our object
        for (prop in obj) {
            // Apply the callback to the object's property and pass
            // the index, the property, and whatever else as arguments
            if (cb.apply(obj[prop], [ prop, obj[prop] ].concat(args)) === false) {
                // Get out if the function returns false
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Reset our object with the new one
    return this.reset(obj);
};
```

The problem is that while the callback is definitely being fired, it doesn't have any effect on the object's property. No matter what I do inside the callback, the changes stay inside the callback's scope.

Here is an example of a simple callback that I've been testing with.

```
var BaseProtoTestObj = new BaseProto();

/** Set some properties to BaseProtoTestObj **/

function cb1 ( key, val ) {
    var prop;

    key = key.toString() + " Callbacked";
    val = val.toString() + " Callbacked";

    for (prop in this) {
        this[prop] = this[prop].toString() + " Callbacked";
    }
}

// Doesn't have any effect on BaseProtoTestObj
BaseProtoTestObj.each(cb1);
```

I can see that there is a lot more going on in jQuery's .each(), but from what I can gather it's for optimization and the ability to iterate over arrays as well as objects.

In the end, my question is simple. **What is it that jQuery is doing to affect the properties, that I'm not in my `.each()`?**

---

**Edit**

I suppose another question to ask would be if my logic is fundamentally wrong, and you *can't* modify an object's properties this way.

Comment: You can see jQuery's .each() [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js). It's at line 610.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a custom method:

```
for(var prop in object) {
   var value = object[prop];
   // do something with value and/or prop
}
```

Although if you really needed `.each()`, you could do something like this:

```
Object.prototype.each = function(cb) {
    for(var propName in this) {
        cb(propName, this[propName]);
    }
}

var foo = { prop: 'value', prop2: 'value2' };
foo.each(function(key,value) {
    // do something here
});
```

Since you need to modify the actual values of the properties, try this:

```
Object.prototype.mutate = function(cb) {
    for(var propName in this) {
        this[propName] = cb(propName, this[propName]);
    }
}

var obj = {
    a: 'foo',
    b: 'bar',
    c: 'baz'
};

obj.mutate(function(propName, propValue) {
    return propName + '-' + propValue;
});

/*
obj will now be:

var obj = {
    a: 'a-foo',
    b: 'b-bar',
    c: 'c-baz'
};
*/
```

Comment: For a lot of cases I probably won't need a custom method, but there are scenarios where applying a callback to each property of the object is preferable. Say that I'm saving something to a redis database for each property of my object. Since the redis library for Node.js is non-blocking, I would have to pass a callback for each save. Also creating functions in a loop isn't a good practice while using javascript, etc.

Comment: Your example is very similar to what I'm trying to do, but as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/btleffler/vuYTP/) it has the same problem as I'm describing in my question. You can't actually modify any of the properties from inside the callback.

Comment: I've been thinking about this in my spare time for a few days and the idea of returning what I wanted to set the property to did cross my mind. For whatever reason it feels like cheating though. For `mutate()` to be safe, I'd have to make sure the callback returned something or else all my properties would be undefined. I don't know if there are any better options though. I'm going to accept the answer, but I'd love it if I could read some more people's opinions. Thanks!

Comment: This is true. However, in my opinion that's the most flexible way, as there's really no way to indicate to the `mutate` function that you didn't change the value. Sometimes you want to change a value to `false` or `null`.